# Is this css block piece correct?if not why?

Tags: html, css

Is this css block piece correct? if not why?

```
.leftnav ul li a {  
text-decoration: underline;  
background-color: red;  
width: 120px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Part is correct :

```
text-decoration: underline;  
background-color: red;
```

**Note:IF you want overlay `text-decoration: underline;` on `a` Element,use of this Property, ٍElse You do not need to use the `text-decoration: underline;` because,The default value `text-decoration` for `a` Element is `underline`.**

> This Part is Wrong:

```
width: 300px;
```

> `a` Tag is inline and inline Elements do not accept `width` property.add `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` to css code for change width.

**Compare This Codes:**

```css
.yourleftnav ul li a {  
    text-decoration: underline;  
    background-color: red;  
    width: 300px; 
}

.myleftnav ul li a {    
    background-color: red;  
    width: 300px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="yourleftnav">Your Code
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Thia is Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="myleftnav">My Code
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Thia is Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's partly valid. Selector is ok, it targets `a`, which is descendant of `li`, which is descendant of `ul`, which is descendant of `.leftnav`.

Declarations are ok, but to apply `width` to `a` (which is inline element), you should add `display:block` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your expectations. Element `a` is an inline element which makes the `width` definition redundant. See below:

```css
.leftnav ul li a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: red;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To make it actually 120 pixels wide, you need to define it as `inline-block`.

```css
.leftnav ul li a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: red;
  width: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```